# Arg parse not returning float

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I am trying to create a function to control the volume of a file.
I dont understand why this error is occurring as I should simply be returning a float

```
parser.add_argument('--volume','-v', default=None, type=float,help='Number  between 0.0 and 1.0 indicating volume level')
    print args.volume

python audio.py -v 0.333338 (terminal input)

    usage: audio.py [-h] [--volume VOLUME] phrase [phrase ...]
            audio.py: error: too few arguments
```

Below is the initialisation of the parser

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--volume','-v', default=None, type=float,help='Number  between 0.0 and 1.0 indicating volume level')
    parser.add_argument('phrase', nargs='+', help="Audio phrase for interpretation")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Can you share how you initialise `parser` please?

Comment: It's not the `volume` argument that's the problem.  It's the `phrase` positional argument, that you have not told us about (but we can deduce exists from the usage line).

Comment: I assumed you could input without the phrase

Comment: The `nargs='+'` means - one or more values is required.  '*' means zero or more.

Answer (score 2):

> `usage: audio.py [-h] [--volume VOLUME] phrase [phrase ...]`

You are missing the `phrase` argument:

```
python audio.py -v 0.333338 some_phrase_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python 2.7.10 and this code snippet work fine:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--volume','-v', default=None, type=float,help='Number between 0.0 and 1.0 indicating volume level')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.volume
```

Try copy pasting same snippet and let me know if it works.
My output looks like this:

```
:-/temp$ python audio.py -v 0.333338
0.333338
```